# Developing Java desktop applications on Microsoft Surface Pro/Pro 2

Tags: java, windows-8

I have a working Java SWING-based desktop application, and I'm being asked if it can be run on the Microsoft Surface Pro or Pro 2. As I understand it, these are using stock Windows 8/8.1 and will be able to run any Windows app normally, is this correct?

Are there any caveats or special considerations when running my app on these devices?

Edit: If it matters, the JRE would be distributed together with the application, so installing Java isnt an issue.

Answer (score 2):

> ... will be able to run any Windows app normally, is this correct?

You will be able to run Java programs, but only in Desktop mode after installing the JRE. Java 7 Update 10 added official support. See [Java on Windows 8 FAQ](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/win8_faq.xml).

By default, Java is not installed on the Surface Pro. There is no `java.exe` or `javac.exe` when attempting to run from the command line. You have to go to Oracle and fetch it.

I was able to install the JRE on my Surface Pro. The package was installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin`. After the install, `java.exe -version` worked from the command line (after fixing `PATH`). The install also included an IE plugin, and it appears to have worked with IE 10 from the tablet. I was also able to install the x64 JRE. I did not try to install the JDK.

There may be something offered on the Windows App Store, too. But I don't use the store, so I don't know.